# which of the function is entire $\sin(\sqrt{z})$ and $\cos(\sqrt{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis

would any one tell me: which of the function is entire $\sin(\sqrt{z})$ and $\cos(\sqrt{z})$.
I have no Idea in which logic I need to apply here.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the Maclaurin series of these two functions?

Comment: Morally: the "function" $z \mapsto \sqrt{z}$ fails to be entire because of the ambiguity in the square root: for any $z$ there are two choices of square root, and there's no continuous way to make a consistent choice on the whole complex plane. When you compute $\sin(\sqrt{z})$, does it depend on which choice of square root you made? What about $\cos(\sqrt{z})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although countinghaus gave a nice informal answer in  comments, I'll add some formal details:
$$\cos \sqrt{z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{(2n)!} \tag1$$
is an entire function. So is 
$$\frac{\sin \sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{(2n+1)!} \tag2$$
 but not $\sin\sqrt{z}$ itself. One can argue from $\sqrt{z}$ being two-valued, but there's another way: since $\sin\sqrt{x}$ does not have a one-sided derivative at $x=0+$, it cannot be extended to an entire function.